# gdb asking to continue/quit?

Tags: c++, gdb

I am new to GDB, using to debug an issue with my program(C++). I used gdb to find the backtrace and then print frames information. During one of the print, let's say the command is something like:

```
1) frame 2
2) print *this
```

In between the output of the print call, I am getting the following line:

`---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---`

Is this expected from the gdb? We should just continue on that message or it means something?

Note: I didn't set any breakpoint or anything, so didn't expect any message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there is too much to print to fit inside the current buffer, gdb will pause after it's hit the limit. If you press enter, it'll continue printing.

I assume `this` points to an object that has a lot of "stuff" in it, so it's perfectly normal that you get this message. Just keep pressing return until you see the information you're looking for or until there is nothing more to print!

(In other words, there is no breakpoint or anything of the sort getting triggered here and nothing happens to the control flow of the debugged program.)